# Add dynamic dependencies to a target with a placeholder

Tags: makefile

I have a target

`%.hgtForCoordsAndNeighbours` (example: `+64-016.hgtForCoordsAndNeighbours`)

that represents a geo coordinate and depends on build steps that are run on all adjacent 1-degree chunks. These (prerequisite) build steps are called

`%.hgtForCoords`.

My problem here is that I need a little calculation to expand from that 1 target name into the 8 (+1 for the centre) adjacent prerequisites and also to enforce the filename structure with the leading zeroes (`%+03d%+04d` in printf).

I have not found a way to express that in Makefile syntax yet so I went for a sub-`$(MAKE)`. Yet that brings its problems with concurrency (`-j ...`) and I think is generally considered bad style to have a `Makefile` call itself. I would also like to learn more about the `Makefile` syntax.

Full example:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

%.hgtForCoordsAndNeighbours:
    # this looks too complicated but that's not the point here. 
    # It's an example for dependencies generated from a target name by a script 
    # and not in Makefile syntax.
    coords=$$(basename $@ .hgtForCoordsAndNeighbours) \
        && echo "Prepare elevation data for $$coords and neighbours" \
        && lat=$$(echo $$coords | grep -Eo '^.{3}' | sed -E 's/([+-])0+/\1/') \
        && lon=$$(echo $$coords | grep -Eo '.{4}$$' | sed -E 's/([+-])0+/\1/') \
        && minLat=$$(($$lat -1)) \
        && maxLat=$$(($$lat +1)) \
        && minLon=$$(($$lon -1)) \
        && maxLon=$$(($$lon +1)) \
        && $(MAKE) -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$minLat" "$$minLon").hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$lat"    "$$minLon").hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$maxLat" "$$minLon").hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$minLat" "$$lon"   ).hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$lat"    "$$lon"   ).hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$maxLat" "$$lon"   ).hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$minLat" "$$maxLon").hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$lat"    "$$maxLon").hgtForCoords \
            $$(printf "%+03d%+04d" "$$maxLat" "$$maxLon").hgtForCoords \
    ;
```

Abstract example what I would like to achieve:

```
%.targetWithAPlaceholder: $(prerequisites generated by a 
                            custom function based on the target name)
```

It is not a problem if that is not too portable. It is only run on a well-controlled environment (currently a Github actions Linux runner with GNU Make 4.3).

In this case it would be OK if all dependencies were evaluated once (since the coordinate space is finite (360 * 180)).

Comment: Why not write a small program that can generate the dependencies, then `-include` its output into the Makefile, the same way that we do for dependency lines created by `gcc -M` and similar?

Comment: If that requires a pre-processor then I'd rather stay with the current sub-make to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to generate the dependencies with a short script.  Perhaps something such as:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for lat in $(seq -90 90)
do for lon in $(seq -180 180)
   do for dx in -1 0 1
      do for dy in -1 0 1
         do printf "%+03d%+04d.hgtForCoordsAndNeighbours: %+03d%+04d.hgtForCoords\n" \
                   $lat $lon $((lat+dy)) $((lon+dx))
         done
      done
   done
done
```

If we call this `generate-deps`, then the (GNU) Makefile lines to ensure it's called and included are simply this:

```
neighbours.mak: generate-deps
    ./$< >$@

include neighbours.mak
```

Comment: Oh, you probably want wrap-around arithmetic for longitude, and omit dependencies on ±91° latitude.  But I'm sure you can manage that yourself.

Comment: Wow, thank you for teaching me that technique.